# Simple variable assignment not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have what looks like to me to be a simple variable assignment not working.

This code is in jQuery, for the context see [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.8.2/src/event.js#L879).

I'm calling:

```
$('#foo').on('someEvent', eventHandlerFn);
```

And I get this issue within the jQuery `on` function.  Here's the starting point:

[image]

As you can see from the console below the code, `selector` is set the my `eventHandlerFn` and the `fn` variable is undefined.  This is as expected.

On line 3509, the value of `selector` is assinged to `fn`.  So, the value of `fn` should be same as the value of `selector`, no??

See below - `selector` is defined, as expected, but `fn` is still undefined.  Why?

[image]

The end result is that my event handler is never registered.

Comment: You pass `eventHandlerFn` variable as a parameter.. what is in that ?

Comment: Please post your code in your question.

Comment: eventHanderFn is just a fn that calls alert.  You can see what it is in the console - it's assigned to the 'selector' variable.

Comment: With a simple event handler like that, you would think that as long as you passed a function that was actually declared and within scope, it would be hard to go wrong ?

Comment: I assume you re-ran the `fn` expression in the console, instead of just assuming it would update automatically, right?

Comment: @JasonP yeah, I reran it

Comment: When you set a breakpoint on line X and the debugger stops at that point, line X has not been run yet. It stops *before* line X runs. If you want to see the result after line X, set the breakpoint at line X+1. Therefore, it is expected that `fn` has not been assigned yet.

Comment: @RoyTruelove, not sure how well the console integrates with the step-by-step code execution, but if you open the ***scope variables*** inside the ***sources*** panel (*where you set the breakpoint*) then you will see that the `fn` is indeed updated.. even if the console does not output it correctly..

Comment: @Zhihao you can see in the last screenshot that the current line is after the breakpoint line, so he has stepped-over that line.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ah, missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the debugger in Chrome - either a material problem or just a nuance of the debugger that I don't understand.  fn does have a value toward the end of the call, but not where the breakpoint is.

Answer (score 2):

The code runs well as shown in the following two screens (*the issue is on how chrome sets the context to the console*)

*It looks like console has access to the variable at definition time (in this case the passed parameters) and not the live values as you run the code*

Before the swap

[image: Before running the line]

After the swap

[image: After running the line]

Comment: Thanks Gaby, not seeing this though.  I used the fiddle linked below and, after having passed line 41, fn is still undefined but selector is not (see image linked below).  Very strange.  http://jsfiddle.net/9xe8r/ and http://i.imgur.com/ote1Ghg.png

Comment: @RoyTruelove what chrome version ?

Comment: I'm on the latest : 32.0.1700.76 m

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any problem with this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9xe8r/). Feel free to edit the jsFiddle to get it to look more like your code.

Can you try putting in `console.log(fn);` after line 3510 and rerunning? Maybe it's just a problem with the debugger?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  I was able to replicate the problem even with this fiddle - see my comment under Gaby's answer.

Comment: @RoyTruelove That's very odd indeed, I'm using that jsFiddle and also set a breakpoint at line 41, fn is defined. What's the error in your screenshot (small x on the top right - probably unrelated). Here's my screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/C9vDtpG.png